# JSTL Count the ForEach loop

Tags: java, jsp, foreach, jstl

I am trying to print some message for every 4 items in the List of items

```
<c:forEach items="${categoryList}" var="category" varStatus="i">
    <c:if test="${i%4 == 0}">
        <c:out value="Test" />
    </c:if>
    <div class="span3">
        <c:out value="a" />
    </div>
</c:forEach>
```

But I am getting below exceptions, seems like `i` is not treated as number

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.core.LoopTagSupport$1Status@3371b822 of type class javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.core.LoopTagSupport$1Status to Number
    at org.apache.el.lang.ELArithmetic.coerce(ELArithmetic.java:407)
    at org.apache.el.lang.ELArithmetic.mod(ELArithmetic.java:291)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstMod.getValue(AstMod.java:41)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstEqual.getValue(AstEqual.java:38)
```

How do I achieve this?

One way is to declare a variable and increment for every loop with the help of scriplets. But I would like to avoid this!

Comment: You can declare a variable and increment it using jstl as well

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The variable `i` is of type [`LoopTagStatus`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/core/LoopTagStatus.html). To get an `int`, you can use [`getCount()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/core/LoopTagStatus.html#getCount%28%29) or [`getIndex()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/core/LoopTagStatus.html#getIndex%28%29).

If you want to print message for 1<sup>st</sup> item, then use:

```html
<!-- `${i.index}` starts counting at 0 -->
<c:if test="${i.index % 4 == 0}">  
    <c:out value="Test" />
</c:if>
```

else use:

```html
<!-- `${i.count}` starts counting at 1 -->
<c:if test="${i.count % 4 == 0}">
    <c:out value="Test" />
</c:if>
```

Comment: Best practice is to use `<c:if test="${i.first}">` to test if first item in loop. see http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/core/LoopTagStatus.html

Comment: nice for .count

Answer (score 2):

`varStatus` is of the type `LoopTagStatus` ([JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/core/LoopTagStatus.html)). So you have to use the property `count` of `i`:

```
<c:if test="${i.count % 4 == 0}">
    <c:out value="Test" />
</c:if>
```